# How to trigger field validation at Ant design form with custom validation func

Tags: antd

I have password reset form:

```
  {formItem(
          props.form.getFieldDecorator('currentPassword', {
        rules: [{ min: 6 },
          { validator: maybeMustBeRequared }
        ],
          })(<Input type="password" />),
          {
            label: tUsers.currentPassword,
          },
        )}
        {formItem(
          props.form.getFieldDecorator('newPassword', {
            rules: [{ min: 6 }],
          })(<Input type="password" />),
          {
            label: tUsers.newPassword,
          },
        )}
        {formItem(
          props.form.getFieldDecorator('confirmPassword', {
            rules: [
              { min: 6 },
              {
                validator: compareToFirstPassword,
              },
            ],
          })(<Input type="password" />),
          {
            label: tUsers.confirmPassword,
          },
        )}
```

my goal revalidates password `password` field when `newPassword` or `confirmPassword` is not empty.

```
const maybeMustBeRequared = (rule, value, callback) => {
    console.log('rule', rule)
    if (!isEmpty(props.form.getFieldValue('newPassword')) || !isEmpty(props.form.getFieldValue('confirmPassword'))  ) {
      // there I want trigger passwor field validation { min: 6}
    } else {
      callback()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your custom validations as normal, and trigger the validation for the specific field based on your case:

```
form.validateFields(['confirmPassword', 'password']);
```

More info about [forcing validation from the docs](https://ant.design/components/form#validatefields-return-sample).

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you don't need such validator in your case, both rules `min: 6` are enough.

But still you can try this:

```js
  passwordLength = (rule, value, callback) => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const confirmPassword = form.getFieldValue('confirmPassword');
    if (value || confirmPassword) {
      rule.validate('confirmPassword');
    } else {
      callback('Im Here');
    }
  };
```

[image: Edit Q-57197421-CustomValidator]